# Include Javascript/HTML 5 code in C#

Tags: c#, javascript, html, xaml, microsoft-metro

Apologize if am wrong, i am developing metro apps using C# am stuck with Flyout,from below links i came to know that Flyouts are not possible in C# and XAML
[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465354) and 
[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465354)
So, is there any way that i can develop flyout in JS/HTML5 and include them in my C# project.
Please Help me, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Popup is a control in XAML that is very similar to a Flyout. You can just use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you right then please try this link:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eternalcoding/archive/2012/07/03/tips-and-tricks-for-c-metro-developers-the-flyout-control.aspx

I don't know what you want to do with the control - so detailed information would be helpful.